# Print all binary numbers of length N

Tags: c

I've done this question on leetcode before but wanted to do it in C. Was wondering if anyone could let me know if there is a better way to do it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void printBinaryLenthHelper(int currentLength, int maxLength, char accum[]) {
  if (currentLength == maxLength) {
    printf("%s\n", accum);
    return;
  }

  accum[currentLength++] = '0';
  printBinaryLenthHelper(currentLength, maxLength, accum);

  accum[--currentLength] = '1';
  printBinaryLenthHelper(++currentLength, maxLength, accum);
}


void printBinaryLength(int length) {
  char accum[length + 1];
  printBinaryLenthHelper(0, length, accum);
}

int main() {
  printBinaryLength(20);
}
```

Comment: To begin with you need to remember that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. That *null-terminated* bit is important, and you don't have it (other than by pure luck). Uninitialized local variables (including arrays) like `accum` are not initialized, their values are *indeterminate* (and seemingly random). That means if the array isn't ending with a `'\0'` (by being lucky) character, you will have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) when printing the string.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you want as desired output?

Comment: Better how? This is very subjective.

Comment: I think he is asking to print all binary numbers with twenty bits from `0` to `1048575`?

Comment: If so, it's prbably better if you use binary operation upon integers and format output them.

Comment: Or simply a loop and a binary output function. As it is (if he wants to print all `1048575` values), that means recursion of at least `1048575` deep - that is a poor use of recursion.

Comment: @david: the recursion is logarithmic, not L near, although the code is so obfuscated that it is not immediately obvious.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid recursion by simply iterating from `0` to `2^n -1`. This range represents all the numbers with binary length `n` (assuming smaller numbers are padded with leading zeroes).

#### Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printBinary(int len) {
    //This loop iterates from 0 to 2^len - 1
    for(int i = 0; i < 1 << len; ++i) {
        //This loop is to print the integer in its binary representation.
        for(int j = len - 1; j >= 0; --j) {
            //  ((1<<j)&i) > 0 evaluates to 1 if the jth bit is set, 0 otherwise
            printf("%d", ((1<<j)&i) > 0);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    printBinary(10);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output

```
0000000000
0000000001
0000000010
0000000011
0000000100
0000000101
0000000110
0000000111
0000001000
0000001001
0000001010
...
```

Tested [here](https://ideone.com/5kPPUf).

**PS**: If you do not understand what `1<<j` and `(1<<j)&j` means, read about bitwise operators in `C`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your function `printBinaryLenthHelper`: you do not null terminate the string before passing it to `printf`. It is also confusing to increment and decrement `currentLength` as a side effect, just pass the next value in the recursive call.

Here is a corrected version:

```
void printBinaryLenthHelper(int currentLength, int maxLength, char accum[]) {
    if (currentLength == maxLength) {
        accum[currentLength] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", accum);
        return;
    }
    accum[currentLength] = '0';
    printBinaryLenthHelper(currentLength + 1, maxLength, accum);
    accum[currentLength] = '1';
    printBinaryLenthHelper(currentLength + 1, maxLength, accum);
}
```

Note also that the name should be `printBinaryLengthHelper`.

Comment: `printf(".*s\n", currentLength, accum);` would also work, without the need for the NUL. Or the NUL could be inserted once in the top-level call.

Comment: @rici: correct. I tried to keep the code as simple and clear as possible. `printf(".*s\n", currentLength, accum);` is simpler but requires a more advanced understanding of `printf` subtleties.